# AWS Glue - disabling bookmarks for some of sources in the job

Tags: etl, aws-glue, data-warehouse

I've got a data warehouse with star pattern - fact table and multiple dimensions around that. They are connected by foreign keys.

I've got two AWS Glue jobs:

1. Populates dimensions (run on-demand, they doesn't change often)
2. Populates fact table (should be run even every hour to get fresh fact data in warehouse)

So the situation is: I've got filled-in dimension tables using first job. In second job I need to get only fresh data for fact table, find foreign keys for each record in dimension table and persist new row in fact table.

Problem is, that when using bookmarks, AWS Glue thinks that since dimension tables didn't change since last run, nothing is there and inserts null as foreign keys.
I tried to disable bookmarking by removing transformation_ctx from the generated script, but it didn't work.

From this:

```
dimension_node1647201451763 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="foobar-staging",
    table_name="dimension",
    transformation_ctx="dimension_node1647201451763",
)
```

I did that:

```
foobaritem_node1647201451763 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="foobar-staging",
    table_name="foobar_item",
)
```

But still those record were not found.

Only solution that I can imagine is disabling bookmarks completely and then add "not exists" checks for all records processed, which would prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to use "foobaritem_node1647201451763" instead "dimension_node1647201451763".

The parameter "transformation_ctx" is optional and when it's informed will be applied bookmark filters.

```
foobaritem_node1647201451763 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="foobar-staging",
    table_name="foobar_item",
)
```